# Why does generated assembly mov edi to variable on stack?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I am a newcomer to assembly trying to understand the objdump of the following function:

```
int nothing(int num) {
    return num;
}
```

This is the result (linux, x86-64, gcc 8):

```
push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
pop    rbp
ret
```

My questions are:
  1. Where does `edi` come from? Reading through some intro docs, I was under the impression that `[rbp-0x4]` would contain `num`.
  2. From the above, apparently edi contains the argument. But then what role does `[rbp-0x4]` play? Why not just `mov eax, edi`?

Thanks!

Comment: The x86-64 System V ABI (used by Linux) passes arguments in registers, unlike x86 (which has too few registers for a reasonable ABI). Other than that, enable optimizations in the compiler (`-Os` or `-O3`).

Comment: Which documentation were you reading?

Comment: Note that you get extraneous instructions in the output because you told the compiler to not optimise your code.  Do not expect optimal code when telling the compiler not to bother with optimisations.

Comment: basically a duplicate of  [Complex compiler output for simple constructor](//stackoverflow.com/q/55329728) (spilling function args), and of [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) in general.

Comment: @rcgldr: The OP already specified x86-64 Linux gcc8.  And even without that, first arg in RDI identifies the calling convention as the x86-64 System V ABI (used on all the major x86-64 OSes except Windows x64).  User-space code has a 128-byte red-zone below RSP that is safe from async clobbers (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/red-zone/info).  (Kernel code has to use `-mno-red-zone`).  The obvious guesses are that this code came from Linux or MacOS.  Given the formatting, probably from https://godbolt.org/, which defaults to x86-64 gcc Linux with no options (default `-O0`).

Comment: @PeterCordes - I wasn't aware of the size of the red zone, and as you commented, there are probably few, if any, non-standard x86-64 environments, even in embedded devices. What is the size for Windows? I deleted my prior comment.

Comment: @rcgldr: Windows x64 only has shadow space, no red zone. :(  Raymond Chen posted a nice article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190111-00/?p=100685  summarizing things across ISAs for Windows: Windows on ARM32 and AArch64 have tiny red-zones, Itanium has 16 bytes, and PowerPC has 232 bytes because of how stack-unwinding via frame pointers is rigidly baked in to the calling convention / prologue and epilogue boilerplate.  (And yes, I'm not aware of anyone using non-standard calling conventions on x86-64 other than the odd hand-written function; x86-64 SysV is well designed :)

Comment: @PeterCordes - Besides Windows (which I wasn't sure if it had a red zone), I was thinking of custom (some are real time) operating systems used in some environments (embedded devices, data capture, ... ).

Comment: @rcgldr: yeah, I understood we were talking about custom RTOS / embedded / whatever.  Any of them that don't have a separate kernel stack wouldn't use a red-zone: you can't use a traditional red-zone on the stack that gets interrupt context, and custom red-zones from rsp-16 to rsp-128 or something might also be impossible:  [Why can't kernel code use a Red Zone](//stackoverflow.com/a/38043511).  But as far as calling convention for register args, and object layout, etc., I assume everyone mostly just uses gcc or clang to build freestanding code like kernels.

Comment: e.g. i386 Linux uses the special `gcc -mregparm=3` calling convention internally (for function calls *within* the kernel), because i386 System V's stack-args convention is inefficient.  But x86-64 Linux just uses the standard calling convention (with `-mno-red-zone`.)

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Where does `edi` come from?
>
> ... From the above, apparently edi contains the argument.

This is the calling convention (for Linux and many other OSs):

All programming languages for these OSs pass the first parameter in `rdi`. The result (value returned) is passed in `rax`.

And because your C compiler interprets `int` as 32 bits, only the low 32 bits of `rdi` and `rax` are used - which is `edi` and `eax`.

Programming languages for Windows pass the first parameter in `rcx`...

> But then what role does `[rbp-0x4]` play?

Using `rbp` has mainly historic reasons here. In 16-bit code (as it was used in 1980s and 1990s PCs) it was not possible to address data on the stack using the `sp` register (which corresponds to `rsp`). The only register that allowed addressing values on the stack easily was the `bp` register (corresponding to `rbp`).

And even in 32- or 64-bit code it is more difficult to write a compiler that addresses local variables (on the stack) using `rsp` rather than using `rbp`.

The compiler generates the first 3 instructions of assembler code before it knows what is done in the C function. The compiler puts the value on the stack because you could do something like `address = &num` in the code. This is however not possible when `num` is in a register but only when `num` is located in the memory.

> Why not just `mov eax, edi`?

If you tell the compiler to optimize the code, it will first check the content of the C function before generating the first assembler instruction. It will find out that it is not required to put the value into the memory.

In this case the code will indeed look like this:

```
mov eax, edi
ret
```